# Throttle comments/votes on the server instead of limiting on the client

Tags: feature-request, rate-limiting

When I submit a comment or vote on a comment, then want to immediately comment or vote again, I get a(n annoying) message that I have to wait 5 or 30 seconds.  Couldn't you just set a timer on the server that wakes up in 5, 10, or 15 seconds and completes the request I just sent instead of making me resubmit the request after waiting.  You'd may (or may not) need to use the AsyncController to do this. Couple this with a modal dialog on the client that dismisses when my request has been completed and you've accomplished the same purpose without me having to submit things twice.  I think it would be a much better user experience.

**Update**:  To prevent gaming the system, you'd want to keep track of pending requests and flush any new requests of the same type while a request is currently pending.  A user simply using the system, i.e., waiting on the modal dialog to dismiss, won't notice this behavior, but a user who submits, then refreshes to gain the ability to submit again more quickly would be blocked.

Answer (score 9):

Then comment spamming could be sent to flood the server request queue. Instead of halting on the "client" side.

Comment: +1. The "annoying" behaviour is surely by design to control exessive human behaviour.

Comment: So flush new requests if there is already one in the pipe.  That would curb abusive behavior, but still work better for people simply using the system and wanting to comment/vote in quick succession.  I much prefer waiting over having to do something twice, especially if I have to wait anyway.

Comment: A queue seems too complex to me. It would be unexpected behaviour if the comment didn't post right away, and even worse if I tried to post 3 comments and the 2nd one got lost along the way.

Comment: Would be a really interesting Greasemonkey project that would see that you got the comment flag, and then hold the comment for X seconds, and then submit it automatically at the end. You would just have to put a little timer somewhere showing how long till your comments are submitted.